# MongoDB node.js driver connection possible memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, memory-leaks

I have been having some trouble with node.js memory leaks and have tracked one down to the minimal code included below.
It simply connects to a MongoDB replication set using the native node.js driver (same behavior using Mongoose also).
Over time the heap used increases (tracked using the HeapDump module below). The garbage collection doesn't seem to clean up everything and increases as shown below.

Do you think this is a memory leak associated with the MongoDB native driver or could it be something else?

Note: I've tried using a promise instead of a callback with no difference and I've also looked for any connection errors and disconnects and never seen any issues with either.

[image]

```js
// Simplest mongoDB connection app
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const db_name = 'proto2';  // 'dev'; 'proto2'
let _db;

require('./HeapDump').init();

// connect to mongoDB database
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://host1,host2,host3/?replicaSet=replSet1', {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, database) => {
    console.log('Connected to db ' + db_name);
    _db = database.db(db_name);
});
```

The HeapDump module is simply this:

```js
module.exports.init = function () {
    setInterval(tickHeapDump, 2000);
};

function tickHeapDump() {
    setImmediate(function () {
        heapDump();
    });
}

function heapDump() {
    let mem = process.memoryUsage();
    console.log('Current memory usage: %j', mem);
}
```

Node modules:

```
npm list --depth=0
├── clusterize.js@0.18.1
├── console-stamp@0.2.6
├── express@4.16.3
├── jquery@3.3.1
├── ldapjs@1.0.2
├── mongodb@3.1.6
├── mongoose@5.3.0
├── socket.io@2.1.1
├── utf8@3.0.0
└── v8-profiler@5.7.0
```

EDIT: Additional testing
So leaving the server running overnight might have provided some more insight or just confused things further for me.

[image]

I'm unsure what does on around 3 hours with the rapid heap increase but there is a very obvious large garbage collection just after 10 hours that seems to keep things under control. I will add back the conditions to check for connection errors and disconnects/reconnects to see if these larger memory changes are related to these events or attributed to the garbage collector alone.

Comment: Hi, these are interesting observations and I'm investigating similar behavior on some of our services as well. It slowly grows over the course of 1-2 months, and sometimes it causes the service to stop "working", like the event-loop seems to stop executing at all. Services that doesn't utilize mongodb doesn't have this behavior. It's just a hypothesis at this point.

Comment: We are also facing similar issue. We are using "monk" as the library for mongodb connections. For we did not even see the 10hr cleanup, it just keeps on increasing. Were you able to nail down that it's because of the driver? Any issue raised on them?